# Cannot insert an explicit value into timestamp column when trying to delete

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm getting the error

> "Cannot insert an explicit value into a timestamp column. Use INSERT with a column list to exclude the timestamp column, or insert a DEFAULT into the timestamp column."

Code:

```
SELECT TOP(0) * 
INTO #TEMP_TABLE 
FROM ACTUAL_TABLE;

DELETE A  
FROM ACTUAL_TABLE A
INNER JOIN ACTUAL_TABLE_2 B ON A.ID = B.ID AND A.SECOND_ID = B.SECOND_ID
```

I want to delete everything from the actual table but it keeps throwing this error

ACTUAL_TABLE_2 only has an ID and Second Id but I don't think that should matter.. but maybe it needs a date? I don't know I'm confused as to why it would be throwing this error. ACTUAL_TABLE does have timestamp columns but I just want to delete them.

Comment: The error means that `ACTUAL_TABLE` has a Timestamp column. Change your `SELECT INTO` and `OUTPUT` to specify all the columns *except* the timestamp one.

Comment: Okay I get that, but why can't I just select all including the timestamp? also I don't think that's the problem either because when I remove the output and deleted* code it still throws the same error.

Comment: Because you can't insert values in the timestamp datatype. Do you understand the timestamp datatype? It is a terrible name and has nothing to do with dates or times. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/rowversion-transact-sql Don't use *, use the names of the columns you want.

Comment: Try running only your SELECT statement without the INTO. That will work. Then try including the INTO.  That will fail.  As Josh and Sean said, you cannot insert TIMESTAMP into a table, even a temp table.

Answer (score 2):

You have to exclude the timestamp field because they can't be inserted into.  To do that, you have to pick all of the other columns manually.  Syntax:

```
DELETE A
OUTPUT DELETED.col1, DELETED.col2, etc INTO #TEMPTABLE (col1, col2, etc)
FROM ACTUAL_TABLE A
INNER JOIN ACTUAL_TABLE_2 B ON A.ID = B.ID AND A.SECOND_ID = B.SECOND_ID
```